# Using xampp/mysql workbench/

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to redirect to a web page on my localhost, I have done all the nessesary configurations from my hosts files and v-hosts it picks up my address from my C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc hosts file which is name.local but does not show the main page. Keeping in mind the site has both front and backend access. I'm new and wanna work on my application locally before i can start editing it on the server.

Comment: Kind provide the codes for your v-hosts conf settings and hosts file. Also provide the errors that you see on your apache error logs so can easily figure out what causes the problem

Comment: Have you edited httpd.conf?

Comment: v-host file   <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/intranet"
ServerName gep.local
ServerAlias gep.local
CustomLog "c:gep.local-access_log" combined
ErrorLog "c:gep.local-error_log"
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/intranet">
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>    host file: 127.0.0.1       gep.local

Comment: I did do some some changes in my http.conf i just removed the # at rewrite modules...eg LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 0):

You posted this additional comment containing your vhost definition and hosts file contents

```
v-host file 
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80> 
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/intranet" 
    ServerName gep.local 
    ServerAlias gep.local 
    CustomLog "c:gep.local-access_log" combined 
    ErrorLog "c:gep.local-error_log" 
    <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/intranet"> 
       DirectoryIndex index.php 
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny 
       Allow from all 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost> 


host file: 
127.0.0.1 gep.local
```

Here are a few suggestions:-

Have you rebooted or restarted the DNS Client to activate your HOSTS file changes.

```
from a command window run started using 'Run as Administrator' do this
net stop "DNS Client"
then once it reports as STOPPED
net start "DNS Client"
```

This will refresh the windows DNS Cache. ( Double quotes are required as there is a space in the service name )

First change `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:80>`

If you are using Apache 2.2.x you also need a `NameVirtualHost *:80` parameter as the first parameter in the vhost definition file. If you are using Apache 2.4.x I believe they removed this requirement so it is not necessary on that version of Apache.

So

```
new v-host file 

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/intranet" 
    ServerName gep.local 
    ServerAlias gep.local 
    CustomLog "c:/gep.local-access_log" combined 
    ErrorLog "c:/gep.local-error_log" 
    <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/intranet"> 
       DirectoryIndex index.php 
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
       AllowOverride All
       Order Allow,Deny 
       Allow from all 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Then of course to test it use the address `http://gep.local' in your browser address bar to get to this new virtual host.